# android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar VectorDrawableCompat IllegalStateException when using support lib 24+

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-toolbar, android-appcompat

I've started a new project in Android Studio and configured my gradle build settings. When I add an android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar to a layout, I get the following error when in design view. Keep note that this error only shows up when previewing with an API less than 21 (specifically APIs 16 - 19). Everything works fine when I preview with API 21 - 24.

I have looked at a number of solutions and tried them, but none have solved the issue. One thing I tried doing was adding this to my gradle:

```
vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
```

But that didn't solve the issue. I tried configuring my compiledSdkVersion to 23, buildToolsVersion to 23.0.3. This did not change anything. If I change the support library versions to 23.4.0 or below, then the issue is resolved. As soon as I change it back up to 24.0.0 or higher then it returns.

Clearing the cache, cleaning the project and rebuilding, and invalidating the cache and restarting did not solve the issue.

```
The following classes could not be instantiated:
- android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)

Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code or show sample data when in the IDE

Exception Details
java.lang.IllegalStateException: This app has been built with an incorrect configuration.
Please configure your build for VectorDrawableCompat.
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.checkVectorDrawableSetup(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:692)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:186)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:181)
at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawable(TintTypedArray.java:67)
at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.<init>(Toolbar.java:298)
at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.<init>(Toolbar.java:229)
...

invalid drawable tag vector
```

Here is my app build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1" // https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/build-tools.html

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.path.path"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 0
        versionName "0.0.0"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    ext {
        supportLibVersion = '24.0.0' // https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html
    }

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${supportLibVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:design:${supportLibVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:${supportLibVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:${supportLibVersion}"
}
```

My project build.gradle is using `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'`

This is the toolbar xml:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/toolbar_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:elevation="4dp"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
app:theme="@style/ActionBarThemeOverlay"
app:popupTheme="@style/ActionBarPopupThemeOverlay"/>
```

And finally, my styles.xml:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar -->
<style name="ActionBarPopupThemeOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark" />
<style name="ActionBarThemeOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/text_on_primary</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/subtitle_on_primary</item>
</style>
```

Is this a bug, or am I just not able to use the support library versions 24 or higher? I'm not aware of any other configurations to change as the exception tried to direct.

[image: design preview]

Answer (score 1):

Check this issue:

[appcompat-v7 24.0.0 is incompatible with rasterized vectors](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=214182)

Comment: It appears this is an issue they need to fix. For now I've kept my settings with sdk 23.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using gradle version greater than 2.0

```
buildscript {
  ...
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
  }
}
```