# app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug java.exe exit value 1

Tags: java, android, gradle, dex

There appears to be a lot of similar issues here on SO, I've tried a number of their solutions but none have worked.

In Android Studio, when I try to run my app either on a physical device or emulator the gradle build fails with the following error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>     com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

I've tried the following:

- Invalidate cache and restart
- Clean Project
- Rebuild Project
- Switch build tools version between 24.0.1 and 23.0.3
- Delete build folder manually
- Create new folder and git clone the project and run it from there
- Set javaMaxHeapSize "3g" in dexOptions
- Set incremental true and preDexLibraries false in dexOptions
- Enable multiDex (even though I am nowhere near 65k methods, still early in the project).
- Open and run a different project. This gave me the same error until I switched build tools around from 24.0.1 to 23.0.1, then it ran fine. When I do the same thing in my current project, I still get this error.
- At one point instead of running it with the play button I ran it with the debug button and it pushed the APK to the emulator but then gave me a ClassNotFoundException for my launch activity and crashed. I renamed/refactored the class name and my original error is back.
- Restarted my computer

I'm running out of ideas, so if you have any please let me know! Here is my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3" // https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/build-tools.html

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "my.app.id"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 0
        versionName "0.0.146"
    }

    dexOptions {
        incremental = true;
        preDexLibraries = false
        javaMaxHeapSize "3g"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    ext {
        supportLibVersion = '23.4.0' // https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html
    }

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${supportLibVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:design:${supportLibVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:${supportLibVersion}"
}
```

**EDIT: Output from Gradle Console**

```
Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2340Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72340Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2340Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72340Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42340Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2340Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest
:app:processDebugResources
:app:generateDebugSources
:app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugAndroidTestDependencies
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugAndroidTestManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugAndroidTestResources
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources
:app:mockableAndroidJar UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 12.859 secs
Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2340Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72340Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2340Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72340Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42340Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2340Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest
:app:processDebugResources
:app:generateDebugSources
:app:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:buildInfoDebugLoader
:app:transformClassesWithExtractJarsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformClassesWithInstantRunVerifierForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformClassesWithJavaResourcesVerifierForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformResourcesAndNative_libsWithJavaResourcesVerifierForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformClassesWithInstantRunForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformClasses_enhancedWithInstant+reloadDexForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:incrementalDebugTasks
:app:prePackageMarkerForDebug
:app:fastDeployDebugExtractor UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugInstantRunAppInfo UP-TO-DATE
:app:coldswapKickerDebug
:app:transformClassesWithInstantRunSlicerForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug
To run dex in process, the Gradle daemon needs a larger heap.
It currently has approximately 989 MB.
For faster builds, increase the maximum heap size for the Gradle daemon to more than 4096 MB.
To do this set org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096M in the project gradle.properties.
For more information see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html
:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 8.85 secs
```

**EDIT: Additional Gradle Output --stacktrack and --info flag**
Alright, here is some additional information that was given when using these flags.
Stacktrace:

```
...
:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:203)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:185)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:66)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:50)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:25)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:110)
    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$4.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:154)
    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:52)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:151)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:32)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:99)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:93)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:62)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:93)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:82)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:94)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.BuildModelActionRunner.run(BuildModelActionRunner.java:46)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:58)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:78)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:48)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:52)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.DaemonHealthTracker.execute(DaemonHealthTracker.java:47)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:66)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.HintGCAfterBuild.execute(HintGCAfterBuild.java:41)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:246)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
    at com.android.builder.profile.Recorder$Block.handleException(Recorder.java:54)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder$1.record(ThreadRecorder.java:57)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder$1.record(ThreadRecorder.java:47)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:173)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:244)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:220)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:231)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:209)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
    ... 70 more
Caused by: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexTransform.transform(DexTransform.java:423)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$3.call(TransformTask.java:178)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$3.call(TransformTask.java:174)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder$1.record(ThreadRecorder.java:55)
    ... 79 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
    at com.android.ide.common.internal.WaitableExecutor.waitForTasksWithQuickFail(WaitableExecutor.java:119)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexTransform.transform(DexTransform.java:364)
    ... 82 more
Caused by: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
    at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.dexOutOfProcess(AndroidBuilder.java:1553)
    at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.runDexer(AndroidBuilder.java:1495)
    at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.preDexLibraryNoCache(AndroidBuilder.java:1766)
    at com.android.builder.internal.compiler.PreDexCache.preDexLibrary(PreDexCache.java:119)
    at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.preDexLibrary(AndroidBuilder.java:1721)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexTransform$PreDexTask.call(DexTransform.java:473)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexTransform$PreDexTask.call(DexTransform.java:427)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
    at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.dexOutOfProcess(AndroidBuilder.java:1549)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.assertNormalExitValue(GradleProcessResult.java:43)
    at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder$3.call(AndroidBuilder.java:1538)
    at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder$3.call(AndroidBuilder.java:1531)
Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
    at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle$ExecResultImpl.assertNormalExitValue(DefaultExecHandle.java:367)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.assertNormalExitValue(GradleProcessResult.java:41)
    ... 2 more


BUILD FAILED
```

The info flag gives the original gradle output with the addition of:

```
Dexing out-of-process
```

right before BUILD FAILED at the end.

Let me also try some of your suggestions cricket_007 from the link you shared.

Comment: Please show more of the Gradle output. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36698816/gradle-what-is-a-non-zero-exit-value-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: Added. Let me see if I can also run it with the suggested stacktrace/info/debug options to get anything else...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you use jdk 1.8 you should use api 24 and before use it make sure that it correctly install
in short v23 is for jdk 1.7 and v24 go wiht api 24 ,jdk 1.8

Comment: That was way too easy... It worked. Strange it was working before, but suddenly decided to stop working... I originally set up the project for api 24, but brought it back to 23 because of another issue I had when previewing with lower APIs such as 16 (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38650995/android-support-v7-widget-toolbar-vectordrawablecompat-illegalstateexception-whe). That issue is back now and app restarts the emulator on lower apis, so I'll have to try setting it up with jdk 1.7. Will accept as answer if the gradle error stays away once I set up jdk 1.7.

Comment: @Programmer001 I haven't tried SDK 24, but with Java  8 installed, you should simply be able to use JDK 1.7 as the compiler in the project settings

Comment: if API 24 is not installed just installed jdk 1.7 and make sure that you the version of jdk in android studio setting

Comment: Yeah I have API 24 installed and jdk 1.8. I went into the project settings and set the bytecode version to use JDK 1.7. It's compiling and running on my physical device. Thanks for the help cricket_007 and Arsene.

Answer (score -1):

Under `aplication` tag in your manifest xml add this line:

```
android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
```

Comment: I already tried that, unfortunately it still gives the same error. Given this also seems to be a work around since I'm well under 64k methods, I'd like to stay away from it if possible.

Answer (score -1):

add like this in gradle:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.0"

defaultConfig {
...
minSdkVersion 14
targetSdkVersion 21
...

// Enabling multidex support.
multiDexEnabled true
}
...
}

dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```